# How to hide react-id element in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've never used javascript before, but I'm trying to write a piece of code that hides the like button and text on Facebook. I've noticed that all elements relating to 'like' being with a 'react-id' tag of '.27'. I thought I could use something like this

```
$(".27").hide()
```

but I always get a null error, same for when I do this:

```
document.getElementById('.27')
```

1. Is there a better way I should be doing this?
2. Can I write a regex (something similar to .27( .* )*) to recognize all tags that start with .27?

Any other resources to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So does it have `id=".27"` or what? If it's literally `react-id` attribute you must select it with `[data-reactid=".27"]` selector. But it sounds dirty anyway. Why do you render them at first place if you don't need them?

Comment: @zerkms data-reactid=".27.something"

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what do you mean? Is there a way to not render all elements with a given data-reactid?

Comment: Well, in your react component you just do not render it. That's it - put some `if` or remove the corresponding line entirely. The problem with your current attempt - is that you try to rely on the `react-id` value which does not have to be of any particular value. It's not guaranteed that what you currently see as `.27` will be the same on next run.

Comment: Ok, I'll dig into the react documentation. Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend using the `UFILikeLink` class instead. ReactID's will not be the same on all browsers (for instance, on my Facebook the `data-reactid` is 0.3.x)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with the following code

```
var like = document.getElementsByClassName("UFILikeLink");
for (index = 0; index < like.length; ++index) {
    like[index].style.display="none";
}
```